# Convert lst with two columns to dataframe?

Tags: r, list

```
 vol=list() ;df=data.frame(name=c(5,2,15,4),name=c(2,0,1,2))
 vol[[1]] <- dplyr::lst(!! names(df)[1] := df)
 df2=data.frame(dat=c(5,2,15,4),dat=c(2,0,1,2))
 vol[[2]] <- dplyr::lst(!! names(df2)[1] := df2)
```

How to convert this list (vol) to adata frame like this:

```
   A     Par    var   
 name    5      2
 name    2      0
 name   15      1
 name    4      2
 dat    5     2
 dat   2     0
 dat  15     1
 dat   4     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to modify the column names in the `list` to commmon names ('Par', 'var') before binding them with `map_dfr`.  As it is a nested `list`, (`flatten` first if it is a nested list) and then do the changes.  If we need the inner list name as column, use the `.id` to create the column with the list names

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
vol2 %>%   
   map_dfr(~ .x %>% rename_all(~ c("Par", "var")), .id = "A")
```

-output

```
       A Par  var
1  name  11   17
2  name  23   12
3  name  94  123
4  name  32   11
5  name   7  117
6  B.Ch  11   10
7  B.Ch  96   10
8  B.Ch   8   10
9  B.Ch  68  133
10 B.Ch   5 1167
```

---

Or using the same method in `base R`, flatten with `c`, loop over the `list` with `lapply` to rename, then create a column with `Map` and `cbind` and finally `rbind` the `list` elements

```
lst1 <- lapply(vol2, setNames, c("Par", "var"))
dat <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, A = names(lst1), lst1))
row.names(dat) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> dat
      A Par  var
1  name  11   17
2  name  23   12
3  name  94  123
4  name  32   11
5  name   7  117
6  B.Ch  11   10
7  B.Ch  96   10
8  B.Ch   8   10
9  B.Ch  68  133
10 B.Ch   5 1167
```

#### data

```
vol2 <- list(name = structure(list(name = c(11, 23, 94, 32, 7), name.1 = c(17, 
12, 123, 11, 117)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 5L
)), B.Ch = structure(list(B.Ch = c(11, 96, 8, 68, 5), B.Ch.1 = c(10, 
10, 10, 133, 1167)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L)))
```

Comment: tha,ks, strange using the first solution i got this error:Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: In the example i give the str is this:List of 2
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ name:'data.frame':.   in my eal example the str is this   List of 2
  ..$ name:'data.frame':.      so   List of 1  does not exist in my real data

Comment: @Tpellirn probably your real example is just a list of two data frames instead of a list of list of data.frame.  Then in that case, you don't need the flatten i.e. `vol %>%   map_dfr(~ .x %>% rename_all(~ c("Par", "var")), .id = "A")` should work

Comment: sorry here is my real data: dat=list(name = structure(list(name = c(11, 23, 
94,32, 7), name.1 = c(17, 
12, 123, 11, 117)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
5L)), B.Ch = structure(list(B.Ch= c(11, 
96, 8, 68, 5), B.Ch.1 = c(10, 
10, 10, 133, 1167
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 5L)))